# How to retrieve the data from referencing side of a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I have a entity class named Question and it have the relationship with the exam class. In order to allow the user access to the list of question that belonged to the particular exam id, I have tried to use the inner join to retrieve the data. However, my attempt is failed. And I have some doubt to clarify with you guys.

**My question**

1. Is the referencing side of the many-to-many relationship allow to retrieve the data with the query that use the inner join?

**My attempt to retrieve data using the question repository**

```java
public interface QuestionRepository  extends JpaRepository<Question,Long> {
    @Query("SELECT q FROM Question q INNER JOIN q.exam_added_question eq WHERE eq.exam_id = :id")
    List<Question> findQuestionListByExamId(Long id);
}
```

**Quesiton class**

```java
public class Question {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "addedQuestion") 
    private List<Exam> addedToExam = new ArrayList<Exam>();
}
```

**Exam Class**

```java
public class Question {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "exam_added_question",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="exam_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    )
    private List<Question> addedQuestion = new ArrayList<Question>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### I think the problem is how you named your fields in the classes and using it in the query. check it compliance.

First of All look at name of your classes and fields. Where is Exam.class, what is the field named **exam_added_question**? And Also what named your id field in classes it's **id**, not  exam_id
Try to change **eq.exam_id** to **eq.id** in the query, Perhaps this solution will help. In JPQL(HQL), we operate with the names of the fields of the classes(Entity fields), and not with the columns in the database table.

```
@Query("SELECT q FROM Question q INNER JOIN q.addedToExam eq WHERE eq.id = :id")
List<Question> findQuestionListByExamId(@Param("id") Long id);
```

Another way:

```
@Query("select q from Question q join Exam eq where eq.id = :id")
 List<Question> findQuestionListByExamId(@Param("id") Long id);
```

The INNER keyword is optional (i.e. INNER JOIN is equivalent to JOIN).

Or select your Question by id. findById() in yours service bean.

```
@Autowired 
QuestionRepository questionRepository;

Question question = questionRepository.findById(ID);
```

Then access the collection of the related entity within a single transaction. Hibernate will do everything for you.

```
List<Exam> examList = question.getAddedToExam();
```

Next step - filtering your examList what you want. Just remember that you need to traverse the collection in the same transaction, because many-to-many relationships have a Lazy strategy by default. Otherwise, you may get a Lazy Initialization Exeption.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Btw the first solution cant work, but the second solution is work

Comment: It show `could not resolve property: exam_added_question`

Comment: Kong Jason , Look at name of your classes. Where is Exam? And Also what named yor id field in classes it's id, not  exam_id

Comment: still have error, `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where exam1_.id=4' at line 1`

Comment: I have followed ur suggestion to changed the exam_id to id, `@Query("select q from Question q join Exam eq where eq.id = exam_id")
 List<Question> findQuestionListByExamId(@Param("exam_id") Long id);`

Comment: it still have error

Comment: I think the problem is how you named your fields in the classes and using it in the query. check it compliance.